# Working with JSON without Maven

Tags: java, json, spring, maven

I am new at web programming study, specifically in Java and a issue came around during the development of an application I'm working on.

I have a Java Web Application(Spring MVC) that i have to consume some data (JSON) from the server in order to construct a chart.

The thing is that all the tutorials that i've seen on the internet mentioned that i have to use Maven dependencies to work with JSON, which my project doesn't support.

Can anyone point me a way to solve this problem without using Maven?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you packaging and deploying your code into server? If you are putting all jars together then just download json jars and put it there. If you are using any other build system (like ant, sbt etc) then use their own convention to specify your dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven is just a dependency management solution. Actually it is more than that but in your context it is. So all you need to do is downloading necessary jars to lib directory and use them. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is simply used by projects for ease of building, reporting and dependency management. If your project does not use maven, you can simply import the jar files for all your dependencies into your project and use it.

So say, for e.g. to deal with JSON to Object and Object to JSON conversions for your project, you decide to use the [Google Gson Library](https://github.com/google/gson), you can simply download the zip or tar from [here](https://github.com/google/gson/releases/tag/gson-2.3.1) and extract the jar file and import it in your project as a Java library to use it. Maven would have only made it easy to maintain these dependencies but it is not mandatory.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries out on the internet which allow you to handle JSON. You could easily find some on Google.

Two examples http://www.json.org/java/, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html